# Command to stop ng-serve

Tags: angular, maven, pom.xml

> because I need to stop it by using script which need to support both window and mac. Please help me to figure out.

Comment: https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/12/4-ways-to-kill-a-process-kill-killall-pkill-xkill

Answer (score 0):

try following if you're using Linux

```
sudo killall ng
```

if it afterwords says that the port is still in use when restarting try following to kill the progress on port 4200:

```
sudo kill $(sudo lsof -t -i:4200)
```

Comment: In cmd.exe try to find PID of port 4200: netstat -ano | findstr :4200

Then kill the process which has Property "LISTENING" with this command(number in command can differ):
taskkill /PID 15940 /F